# Convert list of dates in YYYY-MM-DD format to EPOCH in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R programming and am trying to convert a list of dates in said format (Ex: "2023-02-27") to EPOCH time.

The dates are a column in a data frame, which I am accessing as `DataFrame$Date`.

If I manually pick a date from the table and cast it like so, the conversion works:

```
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2007-02-01"))
[1] 1170280800
```

Yet I'm not sure how I could perform this action on the entire dataframe column.

My understanding of R is rudimentary at best, so I'm not sure what to look up or where I'm doing wrong - any pointers at all would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using this on a dataframe column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it on the whole column with:

```
dataframe$column <- as.numeric(dataframe$column)
```

Or in your case

```
dataframe$column <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(dataframe$column))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! when trying this method, R spits out an error: `Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`. If trying just `as.numeric`, I get this error: `Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion ` (and the column is empty...). If you have any idea what I might be doing wrong - I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: I suspect your Time is being read as a character and needs to be converted to a timestamp. Try using the package lubridate in R! lubridate is essential for handling dates and times.